# Formatting bootstrap card header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

We are rebuilding our site and part of that is using bootstrap. My question relates to the bootstrap  card-header css selector.

```
<div class="card-header">This is my header text</div>
```

I'd like to format that header such that I can have the header text left aligned (which it is by default) but to be able to add a link or button ,etc. right-aligned within the header.

```
<div class="card-header">This is my header text     <a href...>some link</a></div>
```

where the text is still on the left side of the header but the url is on the extreme right hand side of the header.

I know I could build something with basic html, but I was hoping that someone had already found a way to do it using the bootstrap functionality.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With accessing to CSS style Sheet, You can position it using `Flex-box` and with giving padding to .card-header selector to do not position URL in the extreme right side

```
 .card-header{
   display : flex;
   justify-content : space-between;
   align-items : center;
   padding : 20px /*or padding-right : 20px*/
  }
```